# Relationship between row and column range of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, orthogonality

Given matrix $A \in \Bbb R^{n \times m}$ with $\frac{n}{m} = O(n^{\delta})$, where $0 < \delta < 1$, and "nearly orthonormal" rows, i.e., for any $a_i, a_j$ rows of $A$ with $i \neq j$:

$$\|a_i\| = 1, \quad |a_i^\top a_j| \leq \epsilon \tag{condition (1)}$$

where $\epsilon > 0$ is fixed. Define the column range of $A$ as:

$$\text{range}(A) = \{Ax: x \in \mathbb{R}^m\}.$$

Can we find matrix $B \in \Bbb R^{n \times m}$ such that $\text{range}(A) = \text{range}(B)$ but $\|b_i\| = 1, |b_i^\top b_j| > \epsilon$ for all $i \neq j$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks for the edit and pointing out these issues! I meant for all $i \neq j$. Fixed my question to reflect that.

Comment: Where does this problem come from? Please provide background, context and motivation. Knowing the whole story that led to this question can help answer it.